# Skipping rules in iptables

Tags: iptables, rules

Imagine that I have 3 rules in iptables:

1. Check if IP is whitelisted in ipset, then accept it.
2. Check if user tries connect to port 22, then drop it.
3. Check if user tries connect to port 80, then accept it.

This is **example** (not real) of rules:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m set --match-set whitelist src -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

But I would like to do that if user is whitelisted (1st rule), then don't accept it, but skip/redirect it to 3rd rule (skip 2nd rule), like on this picture (**I know that if packet is ACCEPTED then it is done, this is only example, I don't know how to make that jump**):

[image]

So I would like to ask you, how can I set this "skipping" in chain.

**Subquestion:** If it is possible, then is it possible to redirect it to another chain to specific rule too?

**Update:** Real scenario

```
iptables -A INPUT -m set --match-set whitelist src -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -m geoip --src-cc DE -j DROP

... other rules ...
```

As you can see, I whitelisted only Germany, if German's IP pass throught second rule, then I will check it for other rules, but I use whitelisted IPs too.

So if some IP is whitelisted (mostly not German) then I don't want to check if it is German IP (because it would fail) instead that IP should jump into other rules (3rd row) and skip country checking.

**What about go to function?**

Comment: Once the packet is **ACCEPT**ed, then rule processing is done.  IE, once the first rule matches, no following rules matter.  Assuming an ACCEPT/DROP/REJECT action anyway.

Comment: That accept is only example.

Comment: It might help your question if you gave us an example that actually demonstrates a real problem.  Right now it isn't clear to me what you are trying to do.

Comment: As I said Imagine that if IP is whitelisted then I don't want check it for port 22, but skip that rule and check it for the rest rules.. I just want to know how can I skip some rules. Check image, I think it is clear enough :) It is not real problem.. it is only example, as I said :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A custom chain can be used to organize things more easily. There's a an other "terminal" target more useful once in a custom chain: `RETURN` to immediately come back and execute the rule after the calling rule. `RETURN` in the base chain just applies the default policy, so is not so much used.

The asked example becomes:

```
iptables -N whitelist-check
iptables -A whitelist-check -m set --match-set whitelist src -j RETURN
iptables -A whitelist-check -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -j whitelist-check
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Sometimes inverting logic and grouping can work too. For this simple case an equivalent method would have simply been:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m set ! --match-set whitelist src --dport 22 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

**For the updated scenario**: drop everything which is not whitelisted nor from DE (nor ...). For additional exceptions, just add more rules ending with `-j RETURN` before the `-j DROP`

**Update 2**: changed the logic with `DE` since OP changed it too... if, as per OP's change, traffic is dropped for Germany, here, traffic continues for non-Germany.

```
iptables -N filterchain
iptables -A filterchain -m set --match-set whitelist src -j RETURN
iptables -A filterchain -m geoip ! --src-cc DE -j RETURN
...
iptables -A filterchain -j DROP

iptables -A INPUT -j filterchain
... other rules ...
```

Comment: Updated, I added real scenario. What about go to function?

Comment: Ah great, so RETURN just stops custom chain and comes back to parent chain to next rule, right?

Comment: yes. That's the way to do what you want, considering there's no goto

Comment: And goto is for what? And does chains decrease performance, or only rules decrease? If you have for example 4-5 nested chains.

Comment: why did the negation disappear before germany? That changes the result...

Comment: Ah I see now, my logic mistake, and does chains decrease performance, or only rules decrease? If you have for example 4-5 nested chains.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you cannot skip rules within a chain. You absolutely can "jump" to another chain if a rule is matched though. For example, `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -j tcp_packet_chain` will match all TCP packets and jump them into the "tcp_packet_chain". It is important to note though that if the packet is not ACCEPTed or DENYed in the chain you will return back to the next rule in the original chain.